# Use prediction after using get_dummies in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, one-hot-encoding

I found similar question on this topic but no answer was helpful.
I had a data frame with a categorical column in it with 5 different values. I used get_dummies and used linear regression for prediction. Before get_dummies, I had a X_train of 4 columns. After using get_dummies, I got a X_train of 8 columns. Then I used linear regression. However, when I try to use model prediction on a query point, I get error. What is wrong here? I mean, I am giving same size input as in training and testing. But, why I am getting error? How should I feed the model new queries? Here, first 3 are numerical entries and last 5 are dummied categorical value.

code:

```
x= np.array([[120, 2, 3 , 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])

regression.predict(x)
```

Error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-139-32031323955b> in <module>
      1 x= np.array([[120, 2, 3 , 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
      2 
----> 3 regression.predict(x)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py in predict(self, X)
    219             Returns predicted values.
    220         """
--> 221         return self._decision_function(X)
    222 
    223     _preprocess_data = staticmethod(_preprocess_data)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py in _decision_function(self, X)
    204         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'])
    205         return safe_sparse_dot(X, self.coef_.T,
--> 206                                dense_output=True) + self.intercept_
    207 
    208     def predict(self, X):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\extmath.py in safe_sparse_dot(a, b, dense_output)
    140         return ret
    141     else:
--> 142         return np.dot(a, b)
    143 
    144 

<__array_function__ internals> in dot(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: shapes (1,8) and (7,) not aligned: 8 (dim 1) != 7 (dim 0)
```

All in all, how should I give input to model for predicting a new entry after using get_dummies on model? How should my input shape be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two scenarios of why it could happen to you:

1. you lack *constant* in your x now
2. sometimes an additional dummy column with zeros only is added, you might be lacking it now

Also, I recommend that you use statsmodels instead of sklearn to build linear models because it provides more tools to test them.

Comment: Weirdly, giving 2 inputs instead of one, made it work. BTW, thank you for your offer of using statsmodels. I was not aware of it and it gives much more informations.